# How many chapters does "Shokugeki no Soma" season 3 cover?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

*Shokugeki no Soma* season 3 just ended. How many chapters from the manga does this season cover?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E9%A3%9F%E6%88%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)&oldid=74674774#%E7%AC%AC3%E6%9C%9F%E3%80%8E%E9%A3%9F%E6%88%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E_%E9%A4%90%E3%83%8E%E7%9A%BF%E3%80%8F), the 3rd season has 2 cours which cover chapter 120-217(?).

The first cour (*The Third Plate*) covers chapter 120-166:

> 1. Chapter 120-121
> 2. Chapter 122-125
> 3. Chapter 125-127
> 4. Chapter 128-130
> 5. Chapter 131-134
> 6. Chapter 135-138
> 7. Chapter 139-142
> 8. Chapter 143-148
> 9. Chapter 148-149, 151-155
> 10. Chapter 155-159
> 11. Chapter 160-163
> 12. Chapter 164-166, 149-151

---

The second cour (*The Third Plate: Toutsuki Train*) covers chapter 167-217(?):

> 13. Chapter 167-171
> 14. Chapter 171-175
> 15. Chapter 176-179
> 16. Chapter 179-183
> 17. Chapter 184-187
> 18. Chapter 188-192
> 19. Chapter 192-194, 199-200
> 20. Chapter 201-205
> 21. Chapter 194-199, 205
> 22. Chapter 206-209
> 23. Chapter 210-211, 215-217
> 24. Chapter ?